# Circle Angle chasing problem: Compute APC+BQD

Tags: geometry, circles, angle

I was wondering if someone could give me a hint as to how to solve this problem:
[image]

Let circle C1 intersect circle C2 at P and Q. A line intersects C1 at A and B, and C2 at C and D, such that the four points lie on the line on the order A, B, C, D and that P and Q lie on the same side of the line.
Compute APC+BQD.

I found this problem on an angle chasing worksheet by Ray Li. I've tried proving APC+BQD=180°, but I'm unsuccessful because I don't know how to obtain information about the angles. If you have any ideas, please let me know.

Comment: Please provide additional [context](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9960/), which ideally explains why the question is relevant to you and our community. Some forms of context include: background and motivation, relevant definitions, source, possible strategies, your current progress, why the question is interesting or important, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have requested a hint to solve this angle chasing problem. We would like to give you a hint in the form of a diagram, Here, we have extended your sketch by adding a point $E$ and four red lines, i.e., $AQ$, $AE$, $EQ$, and $PQ$. Point $E$ is the point of intersection between extended $DQ$ and the circle $\Omega_1$. If you do the angle chase using these lines, you will be able to compute $\angle APC+\angle BQD$ easily. You have also mentioned that you are trying to prove $\angle APC+\angle BQD = {\large{\pi}}$. We think that you are on track.

[image: TwoCircles]

Comment: Thanks, I was able to complete the problem! I'll put my solution.